# Can't use Angular routerLink in a variable

Tags: angular, routerlink

I'm trying to put a routerLink within  in a const but it doesn't work.

```
const str4 = `<div `+knowmore_style+`>
  <b><a routerLink="/details/` + entry._id + `">
  <img src="assets/icon/add.png" alt="ques-mark" style="width:1em; filter:invert(1)">
  Know More


  </a></b>
```

The button is only clickable when I put  like this :

```
const str4 = `<div `+knowmore_style+`>
  <b><a href="/details/` + entry._id + `">
  <img src="assets/icon/add.png" alt="ques-mark" style="width:1em; filter:invert(1)">
  Know More


  </a></b>
```

Do you know guys how to do?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Because HTML is supposed to be generated (and compiled) by the template, not by the TypeScript code.

Comment: why would you do that?

Comment: Please add details like why exactly are you trying to implement it in this way, what exactly are you trying to achieve here and whether you have added the `RouterModule` to the `imports` array of your `@NgModule`

Answer (score 0):

Would this work by chance?

```
<a routerLink="['/details/', entry._id]"></a>
```